# What is the Space Complexity in Python when using extended slice to reverse a string (ex: string = string[::-1])?

Tags: python

Would it just be O(1) or O(n). I would have guessed O(n) since strngs are immutable in python but I came across a website that said the space complexity would be O(1) for this particular method of reversing a string.

Comment: It's O(n) where n is the length of the string.

Comment: All the answers saying that it's O(n) are correct on the most basic level. You need at least O(n) more space to create a new reversed string. But in the long term, you *might* not be using more memory at all, since once you assign the new string to the `string` variable, the old one could be garbage collected if there are no other references to it. In practice, this is seldom the case, as strings are almost always cached in the CPython interpreter, on the assumption that if you needed a given string once, you may need it again (look up "interned" strings, if you want to know more details).

Answer (score 0):

For *string = string[::-1]* has a space complexity of O(N) and 'N' is length of string. This is because original string remains in memory, and a new string object is allocated to store the reversed version where each character needs to be copy  to new string.
You can use alternate approach like covert string to list and use *.reverse()* & *.join()* or *.join()* with *reversed()*

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python are immutable which means that we cannot modify its content after we create it. If we perform extended slicing on a string as string[::-1], it creates a new string with the reversed content. To get stored, the new string requires some amount of memory which is proportional to the length of the original string (N). It implies that when the input size of the string gets extended, the space complexity also grows linearly with the size of the input. Therefore, the answer to your question is **O(N)** where 'N' is the length of the string.